# Sum of $2$ equal squares also a square

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, pythagorean-triples

[image]

Is there an integer solution to $a^2 + a^2 = b^2$? Because there's this universift that has this logo of the pytagorean theorem where the two squares are equal, but I don't think it's possible.

Comment: Why do you assume that the side of the squares has integer length?

Comment: Both the logo and what it depicts are possible. The Pythagorean theorem holds for *all* triangles.

Comment: @m.a. you're rigth, pytagorean theorem doesn't work only for integers

Comment: I'm gonna go way out on a limb, but isn't the Pythagorean theorem only for right triangles, and not isosceles or equilateral?

Comment: You are just assuming that the two sides are equal. It's perfectly possible that they are close enough that the human eye can't distinguish them from being equal. And you are just assuming that their lengths are supposed to be integers. It's absolute possible with irrational numbers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $a, b$ satisfy
$$a^2 + a^2 = b^2,$$
then (for $a, b > 0$) rearranging gives
$$\frac{b}{a} = \sqrt{2}.$$
However, [$\sqrt{2}$ is irrational](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_2#Proofs_of_irrationality), so there are no positive integers $a, b$ for which this (and hence the original equality) holds, and changing signs shows there are no nonzero integers (regardless of sign) for which it holds.

(Of course, $a = b = 0$ is an integer solution, but surely one you mean to exclude.)

Answer (score 10):

We have $$2a^2=b^2,$$ which rearranges to $$2=\frac{b^2}{a^2}=\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^2.$$

Hence there are integers $a,b$ solving this exactly if $\sqrt{2}$ is rational, which it isn't (see many proofs on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_2#Proofs_of_irrationality)).  Thus there are no $a,b$ as desired.

Answer (score 8):

$2a^2$ is never a perfect square if $a$ is integer. This is because the exponent of $2$ in its prime factorization is odd.

Comment: This one is cool.

Answer (score 2):

OK. So an isosceles right triangle doesn't have integer sides. How about a right triangle with sides that are almost equal?

A nice, and very old, theorem states that a right triangle has rational sides if and only if there is a rational number $\alpha$ such that the sides are in the proportion $\alpha - \dfrac{1}{\alpha} : 2 : \alpha + \dfrac{1}{\alpha}$.

If $\alpha - \dfrac{1}{\alpha} = 2$, then $\alpha = 1 + \sqrt 2$. Wolfram alpha says that the continued fraction representation of $1 + \sqrt 2$ is $[2;\bar 2]$
So we can arbitrarily choose
$$\alpha = [2;2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2] = \dfrac{5741}{2378}.$$

This gives us a right triangle with sides of proportion
$$\dfrac{27304197}{13652098} : 2 : \dfrac{38613965}{13652098}$$
$$ 27304197 : 27304196 : 38613965 $$
which is a right triangle with integer sides and is pretty darn close to being an isosceleles right triangle.